# Can I do a multi recipient transaction for a custom token?

Tags: transactions, token

I would like to know if it's possible to do a transaction with multiple recipient, in order to pay only once the fee.

I saw in the documentation that you can put up to 100 operation in one transaction. Does that mean that I can send tokens to 100 different account in one transaction (and pay only once the fee for 100 accounts)?

I know it is possible with Bitcoin, and not possible with Ethereum (without a smart contract), and if it's possible Stellar will be the right solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fee is per-operation, soyes  you can put 100 'payment' operation inside a transaction, each one with its own recipient, but you will still pay a 100 stroops fee (0.003$ at that time).

This feature is more about validating a bunch at operation at once, versus having to wait for the next ledger close (~5s) for each operation.

What you may need is lighting network, which's currently under development on Stellar.